# How to change the language of a plugin in a specific page?

Tags: wordpress

I would like to know if I can set a plugin to a different language than the one WordPress is using in a specific page.
The site I'm working on is in English, but I need to display a form in Spanish in a single page. The plugin itself has the translation to Spanish (checked using LocoTranslate) but I don't know how to set it in Spanish for that specific page.
I hope I made myself clear, thanks for any help.